# Why this code in Python doesn't recognize the number from a string?

Tags: python, string, integer, numbers, list-comprehension

I have a string that I need to extract the numbers into the string. The "number" has a comma in it. If I delete the comma the function works but in case that I leave it, the functions doesn't works. I need the function to work with the comma. I dont know why, the comma its a problem here.

I will be thankful if someone let me know why the comma it's a problem.
Thank you in advance!

```
def get_numbers(text):
     num = [int(i) for i in text.split() if i.isdigit()]
     print(num)

get_numbers("16,645")
```

Comment: `[int(i) for i in text if i.isdigit()]`?

Comment: ``16,645`` isn't a valid Python literal. What result should ``get_numbers("16,645")`` be? ``16.645``? ``16645``? ``16`` and ``645``? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `split()` method so your code will look like this:

```py
def get_numbers(text):
     num = [int(i) for i in text if i.isdigit()]
     print(num)

get_numbers("")
```

`text.split()` will return `['16,645']`, which you don't want. Use it when you want to separate the string by whitespace (e.g., space, tab, newline).

In this case the `text` string is an iterator over which you iterate. At the beginning of each cycle in the list comprehension a value from `text` will be assigned to `i`.

Comment: This will output a list of single digits as integers. This is not a very useful output, and just getting rid of the comma is probably not what the OP wants. We don't know since we didn't get an answer to the questions in comments, but in Europe and most of South America, the comma is the decimal separator, so we can't omit it.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Yep, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to split text, you can just iterate through `text`

**Code1**:

```
def get_numbers(text):
    num = [int(i) for i in text if i.isdigit()]
    print(num)

get_numbers("16,645")
```

Or if you really want to split the string at the comma.
**Code2**

```
def get_numbers(text):
    text = ''.join(text.split(','))
    num = [int(i) for i in text]
    print(num)

get_numbers("16,645")
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` method is returning `['16,645']`; a list with one string, which is not a digit obviously.

You should use it without `split`:

```
def get_numbers(text):
   num = [int(i) for i in text if i.isdigit()]
   print(num)

get_numbers("16,645")
```